# Negative number output from equation

Tags: vba

I have an equation that requires output to a cell, the equation is attached. The output is returning numbers that should be negative as zero. I know this is simple but having trouble getting the output to work.

```
private sub grade()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim ncolum As Long
Dim nRows As Long
Dim grade As Long
Dim price As Long


ncolum = Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
nRows = Worksheets("Data").Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    production = InputBox("Prduction cost per block($)")
    refinery = InputBox("Refinery cost per block($)")
   ' grade = InputBox("Grade Value (g/t)")
    price = InputBox("Price of comodity ($/t)")
    recovery = InputBox("Recovery (%)")
    quantity = InputBox("Ore Qty (tonnes)")
        'revenue = Grade * price * (recovery / 100) * quantity
        costs = production + refinery
        'Worksheets("data").Cells(i, j) = costs - revenue

For j = 1 To ncolum
For i = 1 To nRows

'input data
    grade = Worksheets("grade").Cells(i, j).Value1
    revenue = grade / (1000000) * price * (recovery / 100) * quantity
    price = revenue - cost
    Worksheets("data").Cells(i, j) = price
Next i
Next j
end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're getting an arithmetic value underflow and truncation, this is why it's usually best to work with `Double`s when your algorithm uses division. The issue here is in the method that your computer is storing the result of the division.

With `Long` variables:

```
Dim n1 As Long
Dim n2 As Long
Dim n3 As Long

n1 = 5
n2 = 2
n3 = n1 / n2

MsgBox "The result of 5 / 2 = " & n3
'This will output "The result of 5 / 2 = 2" instead of the expected 2.5
```

This is due to the fact that I used `n3`, which is a `Long` as the intermediary storage before displaying the expression. If I were to exclude `n3` and append the value of the expression directly:

```
MsgBox "The result of 5 / 2 = " & n1/n2
```

The result would actually be implicitly converted to a `Double` and displayed correctly, but it's hardly something I would rely on.

*Bottom line:* Use `Double`s when division is involved

**EDIT:** I see what the problem is: what's happening is that you are not being explicit about your data types and it's coming back to bite you.

`InputBox` actually returns a String, and since production, price, recovery, etc are not previously Dim'd (and you're not using Option Explicit) the variable are created as a type that will hold whatever it receives in context, in this case `Strings`. In the below screen I entered 500 for both production and refinery.

[image: Debugging screenshot]

Do yourself a favor and read up on [Option Explicit](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) and [Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172744.aspx)

Comment: Changed all variables to double's and is still returning 0 instead of a negative value

Comment: Specifically, what values are showing as negative? It may help to put "Option Explicit" at the top of your module, recompile (Debug -> Compile VBA Project), and then check this again.

Comment: thanks for your help I have re-written with more care and it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try changing price to Double instead of Long?

```
Dim price as Double
```

Comment: Changed all variables to double's and is still returning 0 instead of a negative value